# Dropwizard 404 error on available route

Tags: java, dropwizard

I'm getting 404 on available route which is a put request.

So the message I'm getting is:

```
6_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.122 Safari/537.36" 93
INFO  [2015-02-16 02:38:13,326] org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener: Session Metrics {
    42205 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
127.0.0.1 -  -  [16/Feb/2015:02:38:13 +0000] "PUT /users/2/rules/current HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.122 Safari/537.36" 15
```

Is there a way to debug this or fix if above information is enough?

I have checked the route and its parameters and they all look fine.

Comment: you should put the resource class here as well.

Comment: Are you sure that you registered your resource? Please also post the payload of your request when you add your code to the question.